# How to redirect 404 pages to hashbang url in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I want to redirect 404 pages to hashbang url in ASP.NET.
For example;

```
example.com/login --> example.com/#!/login
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to capture all errors in the `Application_Error` event of the `global.asax` and then redirect to the hashbang URL based on the error type.